# Can a series change from increasing to decreasing or vice versa?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The conditions for the integral test and comparison test state that in order to determine the convergence of a series, the terms need to be positive and decreasing 'eventually'. But how can a series have negative terms that become positive and then start decreasing and still be considered a series? Are there any examples of such a series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A series is just an infinite sequence of numbers that we sum up. Whether or not it converges or not does not matter.

For example, a convergent series that fits your requirements is

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n
$$
With $a_0 = -1, a_1 = 1, a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}\text{ for } n\ge 2$.